# how to bind grid to form mvc extjs 4 With the grid data from MYSQL and PHP

Tags: extjs, model-view-controller, grid

hi i just learning ext js few months, I want to create a GUI like http://loianegroner.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/extjs4-mvc-grid-binded-form-loiane.jpg  . when an item is clicked will fill the form . any suggestion how to make it??

**Update**

This is my code, 
But Grid no bind to form when item click on grid, What is wrong?

**Controller: Detail.js**

```
Ext.define('UserApp.controller.Detail', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
   stores: ['User'],
    models: ['User'],
    views: ['user.Detail','user.listDetail'],
    refs: [{
        ref: 'Detail',
        selector: 'form'
    }],
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'listDetail': {
                selectionchange: this.gridSelectionChange,
                viewready: this.onViewReady
            }
        });
    },
    gridSelectionChange: function(model, records) {
        if (records[0]) {
             console.log('clicked item');
             this.getDetail().getForm().loadRecord(records[0]);
        }
    },
   onViewReady: function(grid) {
        grid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
    }    
});
```

**Model:User.js**

```
Ext.define('UserApp.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'userID',
    fields: [
            {name: 'userID',   type: 'int'},
            {name: 'name'},
            {name: 'lastname'},
            {name: 'age',   type: 'int'},

            ]
});
```

View : Detail.js// form show data item click on grid

```
Ext.define('UserApp.view.user.Detail' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    alias : 'widget.Detail',

    margin: '0 0 0 10',

    title:'Company details',

    defaults: {
        width: 240,
        labelWidth: 90
    },

    defaultType: 'textfield',

    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'userID',
        name: 'userID'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'Nama',
        name: 'name'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'lastname',
        name: 'lastname'
    },{
        fieldLabel: 'age',
        name: 'age'
    }]
    });
```

**View: listDetail.js// Show grid data**

```
Ext.define('UserApp.view.user.listDetail' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.listDetail',
   // id:'userID2',
    store: 'User',
    title : 'Users',
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        store: 'User',   
        dock: 'bottom',
        displayInfo: true
    }],
    initComponent: function() {

        this.columns = [
            {
            header: 'ID',
            dataIndex: 'userID',
            flex: 1
            },
            {
            header: 'Name',  
            dataIndex: 'name',  
            flex: 1
            },
           // {header: 'Last Name',  dataIndex: 'lastname',  flex: 1},
           // {header: 'Age', dataIndex: 'age', flex: 1}
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has no idea about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Thisis straight out of Sencha docs. The first stop for you would be to gotrough this example and study it line by line:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/grid/binding-with-classes.html

Then you can take a look at the exact code that rendered the image you included in your question:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#form-grid

Comment: dbrin: Please see my code.. grid no bind to from, what wrong?? thank